# String data manipulation with Maps for very large data input

Tags: java, string, data-structures, hashmap, substring

I have solved **Two Strings** problem in HackerRank

Here is the problem.

> Given two strings, determine if they share a common substring. A
>   substring may be as small as one character.
>
> For example, the words "a", "and", "art" share the common substring.
>   The words "be" and "cat" do not share a substring.
>
> **Function Description**
>
> Complete the function twoStrings in the editor below. It should return
>   a string, either YES or NO based on whether the strings share a common
>   substring.
>
> twoStrings has the following parameter(s):
>
> s1, s2: two strings to analyze .
>
> **Output Format**
>
> For each pair of strings, return YES or NO.

However, when extra-long strings are subjected, my code does not run within the time limit. Any suggestions to improve efficiency? I think I can improve substring finding with using the Stream API. But I'm not sure how to use it in this context. Could someone please help me to understand this better?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "hi";
    String s2 = "world";
    checkSubStrings(s1, s2);
}

static void checkSubStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    Map<String, Long> s1Map = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Long> s2Map = new HashMap<>();
    findAllSubStrings(s1, s1Map);
    findAllSubStrings(s2, s2Map);
    boolean isContain = s2Map.entrySet().stream().anyMatch(i -> s1Map.containsKey(i.getKey()) );
    if (isContain) {
        System.out.println("YES");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
}

static void findAllSubStrings(String s, Map<String, Long> map) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        String subString = s.substring(i);
        for (int j = subString.length(); j > 0; j--) {
            String subSubString = subString.substring(0, j);
            if (map.containsKey(subSubString)) {
                map.put(subSubString, map.get(subSubString) + 1);
            } else {
                if (!subSubString.equals(""))
                    map.put(subSubString, 1L);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I just solved the question using HashSets.

I optimized the code using Set. Now it runs with very large Strings.

```
static String twoStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    String result = null;
    Set<Character> s1Set = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Character> s2Set = new HashSet<>();
    for(char a : s1.toCharArray()){
        s1Set.add(a);
    }
    for(char a : s2.toCharArray()){
        s2Set.add(a);
    }
    boolean isContain = s2Set.stream().anyMatch(s1Set::contains);

    if(isContain){
        result = "YES";
    } else {
        result = "NO";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What's the **Two Strings** problem? Please describe the problem you are trying to solve. It looks like you're just trying to check if there is any substring of one string in the other - it would presumably be sufficient to check only for single characters in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 2 strings share an N (>=2) character substring, they also share an N-1 character substring (because you can chop a character off the end of the common substring, and this will still be found in both strings). Extending this argument, they also share a 1-character substring.

As such, all you need to check are single-character substrings.

Fill your maps with single-character substrings instead, and you will avoid creating (and checking) unnecessary substrings. (And just use a Set instead of a Map, you never use the counts).

```
// Yields a `Set<Integer>`, which can be used directly to check.
return s.codePoints().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Thank you! Your direction was really helpful. I just had to see if single character substrings from one string, are available in the other string. Did that using a Set and it worked like a charm.